# adding project to python path doesn't work

Tags: python, import, module

I want to test my scrapy spider. I want to import spider to a test file an make a test spider and override start_urls, but I have a problem with importing it. Here is a project structure

```
...product-scraper\test_spider.py
...product-scraper\oxygen\oxygen\spiders\oxygen_spider.py
...product-scraper\oxygen\oxygen\items.py
```

the problem is that spider import Product class from items.py

```
from oxygen.items import Product
ImportError: No module named items
```

cmd`scrapy crawl oxygen_spider` works

I tried change sys.path or site.addsitedir in all possible ways

```
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
module_path = os.path.join(basedir, "oxygen\\oxygen") 
sys.path.append(basedir)  # module_path
```

no success :(

I use python 2.7 on windows

Answer (score 0):

Do you really get the error "No module named items"? Or is it something like "No module named oxygen.items"?
Also I'm not really sure why you would want to use os.path commands. Wouldn't this just work:

```
from items import Product
```

So without the "**oxygen.**" This would however, as far as I know, only work if Product is a class in your items.py. If it's not a class I would suggest to just use:

```
import items
```

If that does not work, please specify what Product is in your items.py

Comment: I work because I run spider from oxygen folder, so items are in oxygen/items.py. the test howere is one higher